# Use Ruby hash value inside of hash

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
numbers = {
  "one" => "two",
  "three" => numbers["one"] }
```

I know I can just make the hash and set everything normally like `numbers["one"]` but ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `numbers` is not yet defined, but you can make the items assigned more than once a variable:

```
# seems odd, but ok...
def_num = "two"
numbers = { 'one' => def_num, 'two' => def_num }
```

Comment: It's because of chained paths I wanted to do something like that :P

Comment: Well, you can't do that.  If my suggestion won't work for some reason please post what you are actually trying to accomplish and some real input/output instead of a trivialized example.

Comment: It did work perfectly, I just slightly modified it to just have the hash overwrite the original value which was the root path; instead of creating a new container.  Thanks!  I didn't think about doing that >.<